# Autofill column in MySql based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql db with two columns A and B where A is an autoincrement. Is there any way to autofill a column C whenever an entry is inserted using Hibernate. The column C will be the concatenation of values in B and A i.e. B_A?

Comment: It is not a good idea to save one Information two times

Comment: `create view v as select a, b, concat(a, b) ab ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER (https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_insert.php) which can change values for your insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER addRow BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      SET new.C = concat(new.a, '_', new.b);
  END
```

Edit:
You can fetch the auto increment value using:

```
DECLARE next_id INT;
   SET next_id = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='tbl');
   SET NEW.field=next_id;
```

Comment: The autoincrement field will give a value as 0 instead of the value it is going to take.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query :

```
SELECT CONCAT(char_col,'_',CAST(int_col AS CHAR));
```